# Cannot get sum of every time a word appears in a column using SQLDF

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I have a huge data set with a column named `day_of_week` which basically tells the day of the week on which an accident happened.  In this column, it lists `"SUNDAY"` or `"MONDAY"` or `"TUESDAY"`, etc.

What I need to be able to do is to figure out how many accidents happened on Sunday, but for this class I have to use SQL to solve the problem.

`marylandResult` is the name of my data frame and I'm using `X` to store the result.  Here is the code I've been trying:

```
X <- sqldf('select marylandResult.day_of_week where marylandResult.day_of_week="SUNDAY"'
```

Sunday is all caps in the database and it shouldn't matter using SQL code if it is all caps or not, but since my code has not been working, I've tried following all caps.

When I run this code I get an answer of `0 rows or observances` when I look at `X`.  This obviously is not true because I can see there are a ton of instances.  Other than this I've tried several variations on this code where I use a different column name to try and pull out the answer.  I've been told as a general rule to watch out for spaces, but I don't know if that is tripping me up here or not.

```
X <- sqldf('select marylandResult.day_of_week where marylandResult.day_of_week="SUNDAY"'

X <- sqldf('select marylandResult.case_number where marylandResult.day_of_week="SUNDAY"'

X <- sqldf('select marylandResult.day_of_week where day_of_week="SUNDAY"'
```

I should get somewhere in the neighborhood of 2375 results but so far I keep getting 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is `select ... from ... where ...` so using the test data shown in the Note at the end we use the following code.  (There was a reference to case insensitivity in the question so `collate nocase` was added but that can be omitted if not needed.)

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select count(*) as Count 
  from marylandResult 
  where day_of_week = 'SUNDAY' collate nocase")
##   Count
## 1     2
```

### Note

Questions should be complete and verifiable including reproducible input data.  I have provided it for you this time.

```
marylandResult <- data.frame(day_of_week = c("TUESDAY", "SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "SUNDAY"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  I don't really understand what you did under the note portion, however, or what you meant.  Sorry, relatively new to R and trying to learn.

Comment: Questions should include the input in a form that can be copied and then pasted into R.  If you copy and paste the code in the Note into an R session it will create the indicated test data frame.